# Streaming media from PC or Laptop to Mobile or another PC on VLC

Tags: open-source, streaming, dlna, vlc, upnp

I would like to stream from my local PC/Laptop which is connected to my local WiFi to some other device which could be mobile/PC/Laptop which is also connected to the local WiFi over VLC.

Something similar to the way you can stream YouTube videos on VLC.

If it's not possible to stream on VLC. I would like support for

- Playback speed (1x, 1.5x, 2x etc)
- Seek
- Subtitles support (It's good if it can automatically pick up subtitles)
- Audio support (In case of multiple audio)

It would be great if the solution is FREE.